# Limit with linear functions properties

Tags: calculus

Let be $L:R^n \to R^m$  a linear function. Prove that if $$\lim_{h\to 0}  \Vert (L(h)/ \Vert h \Vert) \Vert=0 $$ then L is the zero constant.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are given
$$\lim_{h\to 0}(\|Lh\|/\|h\|)=0$$.

Note that, by linearity of $L$ and the scaling property of the norm, $$\frac{\|L(\lambda h)\|}{\|\lambda h\|}$$ is independent of $\lambda\neq 0$.  So we must have $$\| Lh\|=0$$ for all $\|h\|=1$ and hence all $h$ by linearity, i.e., $L=0$.